# Session lost and user logs out on external redirect from payment gateway in Django Oscar

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, django-oscar

I've integrated a 3rd party payment gateway in Django Oscar. On checkout user is redirect to Payment Gateway where user fills payment details and on successful payment, the payment gateway post back success response to my custom URL on my website. But when I receive the response, user becomes anonymous, session data is lost and user is logged out of the website on redirect to **ThankYou** page.

The user stays logged in until I redirect to another view using `HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`.

The **ThankYou** view is a simple Template view.

Here are my middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```

Please guide me if someone has solved this issue before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is almost certainly that your session cookie's `SameSite` attribute is set to `Lax`, which is the Django [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite). This means that the cookie is "blocked in CSRF-prone request methods (e.g. POST)" - so if you have a POST request directly from a third party site this cookie will be blocked, and it will seem to you like the user isn't logged in.

Your options are:

1. Change `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE` to `None`, and accept the security implications of that as described in the documentation (this isn't ideal).
2. Modify your view logic so that the view that receives the POST request redirects the user to another view, making sure not to write anything to the session while doing that. You then have to make sure that any data received in the POST is stored properly elsewhere so that you can retrieve it again after the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So now whenever I receive response in 1 view then I simple redirects it to another view but still user is being logged out.

Comment: You must be writing to the session somewhere in that view, or in your middleware.